# Correct Approach to Recursively Summing Map in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, idioms

I have just started a project in work where we are migrating some C# tooling across to a new Scala project. This is my first exposure to the language (and functional programming in general) so in the interest of not just writing Java style code in Scala, I am wondering what the correct approach to handling the following scenario is.

We have two map objects which represent tabular data with the following structure:

```
map1       key|date|mapping val

map2       key|number
```

The mapping value in the first object is not always populated. Currently these are represented by `Map[String, Array[String]]` and `Map[String, Double]` types.

In the C# tool we have the following approach:

- Loop through key set in first map
- For every key, check to see if the mapping val is blank
- If no mapping then fetch the number from map 2 and return
- If mapping exists then recursively call method to get full range of mapping values and their numbers, summing as you go. E.g. key 1 might have a mapping to key 4, key 4 might have a mapping to key 5 etc and we want to sum all of the values for these keys in map2.

Is there a clever way to do this in Scala which would avoid updating a list from within a for loop and recursively walking the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
@annotation.tailrec
def recurse(key: String, count: Double, map1: Map[String, String], map2: Map[String, Double]): Double = {
  map1.get(key) match {
    case Some(mappingVal) if mappingVal == "" =>
      count + map2.getOrElse(mappingVal, 0.0)
    case Some(mappingVal) =>
      recurse(mappingVal, count + map2.getOrElse(mappingVal, 0.0), map1, map2)
    case None => count
  }
}
```

example use:

```
val m1: Map[String, String] = Map("1" -> "4", "4" -> "5", "5" -> "6", "8" -> "")
val m2: Map[String, Double] = Map("1" -> 1.0, "4" -> 4.0, "6" -> 10.0)

m1.map {
  case (k, _) => k -> recurse(k, 0.0, m1, m2)
}.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(1,14.0)
(4,10.0)
(5,10.0)
(8,0.0)
```

Note that there is no cycle detection - this will never terminate if map1 has a cycle.

Comment: Yes this looks like what I was struggling to accomplish - many thanks :)